# Can i increase the Gateway Timeout in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to run a SQL query connected to a Azure SQL database, but I get an error

> Gateway Timeout

after 2 minutes. The logic app design is very simple, run 1 daily and then run the SQL query.

Is there a way to increase this timeout or another way to overcome
this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a consumption or standard LogicApp?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first thing you must consider is to optimize the query or queries involved. 2 minutes waiting for result data set is just too much. Make sure indexes exists that support the query, and perform maintenance of indexes and statistics also.

If you tried to optimize the query already, you can add/set the [ServiceProviders.Sql.QueryTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal#reference-for-app-settings---localsettingsjson) setting on the workflow app settings to the value you want. By default, is set to 2 minutes. If you [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal#add-an-app-setting-in-the-portal) the value "00:05:00" then it would be 5 minutes the timeout limit.